# I am getting a require() of ES Module error using `npm install semantic-ui-dropdown` command

Tags: semantic-ui

I just tried to install semantic-ui on two different machines and received the same error:

`npm ERR! Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /Users/petelombardo/node_modules/del/index.js from /Users/xxx/node_modules/semantic-ui/tasks/clean.js not supported.

npm ERR! Instead change the require of index.js in /Users/xxx/node_modules/semantic-ui/tasks/clean.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.`

Please advise.  Thank you.

results outlined in the video [here](https://semantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started.html#:%7E:text=install%20%2Dg%20gulp-,Install%20Semantic%20UI,-Semantic%20UI%20is).

Answer (score 1):

The semantic ui repo hasnt been updated since 2018, it seems to be a dead project. There is a community fork called fomantic-ui, try using that instead, it doesnt have this issue as its still being maintained.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).